# How to create readonly Excel sheet using C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am creating a dynamic Excel sheet using ExcelWorksheet. I need to create a non-editable excel. **ws.Cells["A1:Q12"].Style.Locked = true** is **not working**.

Here is my code :

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Download/Sample.xlsx");
      using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
      {
       FileInfo summaryFilePath = new FileInfo(filePath);    
       ExcelWorksheet ws= pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Page");
       CreateForamters(ws);
      }
    }



 private void CreateForamters(ExcelWorksheet ws)
    {
        ws.Cells["B8:L8"].Value = "SamplePage";           
        ws.Cells["B10:L10"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM-yy");
        ws.Cells["B11:L11"].Value = "test data........-";

        ws.Cells["B8:L11"].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        ws.Cells["B8:L11"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        ws.Cells["B8:L11"].Style.Font.Name = "Arial";
        ws.Cells["B8:L11"].Style.Font.Size = 16;
        ws.Cells["B8:L11"].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Blue);
        ws.Cells["B8:L11"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.White);
        ws.Cells["B8:L11"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        ws.Cells["B8:L8"].Merge = true;
        ws.Cells["B9:L9"].Merge = true;
        ws.Cells["B10:L10"].Merge = true;
        ws.Cells["B11:L11"].Merge = true;
        ws.Cells["A1:Q12"].Style.Locked = true;
    }
```

Thank you all in advance for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am creating a dynamic Excel sheet using ExcelWorksheet. I need to create a non-editable excel. ws.Cells["A1:Q12"].Style.Locked = true is not working.

To create NON-Editable Cells, you have to use

```
ws.get_Range("A1", "Q12").Locked = true;
```

And then you need to protect the worksheet. Without protecting the worksheet, the `.Locked` command doesn't have any significance.

Here is a basic example (*TRIED AND TESTED IN VS2010 + OFFICE 2010*)

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

ws.get_Range("A1", "Q12").Locked = true;

string Password = "Sid";

ws.Protect(Password, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

**NOTE**: By default all cells in Excel are locked. If you don't want to protect the rest of the cells in the sheet then remember to set their `.Locked` property to `False`.

```
ws.Cells.Locked = false;
```

and then use the above code.

Comment: im not getting ** ws.get_Range ** property

Comment: Which VS version are you using?

Comment: Hmm Strange. As mentioned, I have tested it in VS 2010 C#

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save Excel WorkBook as `ReadOnly` Save as Below:

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

ExcelWorkBook.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(save_path, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue , misValue , True, True,XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, false, false, misValue, misValue , misValue );
```